# Combine two data sets and multiply certain variables

Tags: sas

I have two data sets that I want to combine in the following way. I want to join two data sets which I know how to do, joining on nameid and also showing variables such as roof and wall but then I want to multiply a set of variables such as V1-V2 without specifying all of the variable names. If the variable in the two data sets is named the same (except for the nameid) I want to multiply them.

| NAMEid | ROOF | V1 | v2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | RED | 1 | 0 |
| two | BLUE | 1 | 0 |
| three | BLUE | 1 | 0 |

| NAMEid | WALL | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | GREEN | 1 | 0 |
| two | BLACK | 0 | 0 |

Desired result

| NAMEid | ROOF | WALL | V1 | V2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | RED | GREEN | 1 | 0 |
| two | BLUE | BLACK | 0 | 0 |
| three | BLUE | . | 0 | 0 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one solution that uses base SAS functions. There is probably a much more elegant solution with IML or even with base SAS.

The main problem we have is that SAS will automatically overwrite data if the columns have the exact same name. The strategy here will be to rename the columns in one dataset and check them against the other dataset. We'll need to do this logically so that we can easily compare names.

First, we'll create some code that gets all the variables from each dataset. We'll also generate code that renames the variables in the second dataset:

```
proc sql noprint;
    select name
    into :vars_have1 separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     memname = 'HAVE1'
          AND libname = 'WORK'
          AND type    = 'num'
    ;

    select cats('_', name) as new_name
         , cats(name, '=', calculated new_name)
    into :vars_have2 separated by ' '
       , :rename separated by ' '
    from dictionary.columns
    where     memname = 'HAVE2'
          AND libname = 'WORK'
          AND type    = 'num'
    ;
quit;
```

If we look at `&rename`, we'll see we've created some code to help us rename all of the variables in the second dataset:

`V1=_V1 V2=_V2`

We've added an underscore to all the variable names. This will make it easy for us to compare later. We can place this in a `rename=()` dataset option.

Next, we'll take a double-loop approach where we'll check every variable against each renamed variable. Remember that underscore we added to the second dataset's variables? We're going to ignore that. Using arrays, the `vname` function and `scan()`, we're able to compare all numeric variables in `have1` with all numeric variables in `have2`.

```
V1 = V1? Yes. Stop and multiply.
V2 = V1? No. Keep checking.
V2 = V2? Yes. Stop and multiply.
```

This is what that code looks like:

```
data want;
    merge have1(in=h1)
          have2(in=h2 rename=(&rename.) )
    ;
    by NAMEid;

    array vars1[*] &vars_have1;
    array vars2[*] &vars_have2;

    if(h1 = h2) then do i = 1 to dim(vars1);
        do j = 1 to dim(vars2);
            if(upcase(vname(vars1[i])) = scan(upcase(vname(vars2[j])), 1, '_') ) then do;
                vars1[i] = vars1[i]*vars2[j];
                leave;
            end;
        end;
    end;
        else do i = 1 to dim(vars1);
            vars1[i] = 0;
        end;

    drop i j &vars_have2;
run;
```